# １つの列の２つのグループ（男女）から四分位の変数を作成→新しい１つの変数を作成→正確に分類できているかの確認まで教えてください。

Tags: r

下記のようなデータフレームで、男女別にBPの四分位変数（BPq）を作成し、それぞれの下位25％を新変数（lowBP）=　1（その他は0）として作成したいです。

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:4, age = c(43, 62, 54, 55), sex = c(0, 1, 1, 0), group = c(1, 2, 3, 3)
    BP = c(120, 130, 132, 110), BMI = c(21, 26, 23, 19))
```

以下のコードで試みていますが、正確に分類（男女別に）できているかが不明です。変数の確認方法までご教示いただけると助かります。

```
# 男女別のBP四分位変数を作成
df <- df |> group_by(sex) |> mutate(BPq = ntile (BP,4))

# 男女それぞれの下位25％をlowBP=1と定義
df <- df |> mutate(lowBP = case_when(BPq == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既に解決済みと思われますが念のための御参考です。
グルーピングしてグループ内を値の大小で分割するコードの確認方法として `arrange()` を使う実施例を下記に示します。ただし，提供データでは分割数（4）に対して対象データ数（2）が少ないので得られる情報も限られます。

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                 age = c(43, 62, 54, 55),
                 sex = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
                 group = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                 BP = c(120, 130, 132, 110),
                 BMI = c(21, 26, 23, 19))
df <- df |>
    group_by(sex) |>
    mutate(BPq = ntile(BP, 4),
           lowBP = case_when(BPq == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
df |>
    select(ID, sex, BP, BPq, lowBP) |>
    arrange(BP, .by_group = TRUE)

## # A tibble: 4 × 5
## # Groups:   sex [2]
##      ID   sex    BP   BPq lowBP
##   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
## 1     4     0   110     1     1
## 2     1     0   120     2     0
## 3     2     1   130     1     1
## 4     3     1   132     2     0
```